# Slice categories and dependent types

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, topos-theory, type-theory

How are slice categories related to dependent types ? Here is a quote from Mclarty's book *Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes* that made me wonder about this:

*high-level programming languages have dependent types, data types which themselves depend on parameters in other data types.*

So I am wondering what the general connection is. An example in Idris would be great, but not necessary.

Comment: Short story: an object of $\mathcal{C}/I$ is the category theoretic interpretation of an "$I$-indexed family of objects of $\mathcal{C}$". The longer story is that of [display map categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/display+map).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can model a dependent type theory in a locally cartesian closed category $\mathcal{C}$:

- A closed type is interpreted as an object;
- A term is interpreted as a morphism;
- A dependent type upon $X$ is interpreted as an object of the **slice category** $\mathcal{C}/X$.

Substitution of terms in types is interpreted as a pullback between the slices of C.

This was proposed by Seely in his seminal paper [Locally cartesian closed categories and type theory](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~rags/LCCC/LCCC.pdf).

Comment: Very good answer, very much to the point. To give one further remark: A family $(B_a)_{a \in A}$ of sets (hence a dependent type "$a : A \vdash B_a : \mathrm{Type}$") gives rise to an object in $\mathrm{Set}/A$, namely the set $\coprod_{a \in A} B_a$. The functor $\mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Set}/A$, $X \mapsto (X \times A \to A)$ ("constant family") has adjoints on both sides. The left adjoint computes the dependent sum and the right adjoint computes the dependent product.